# Upgrading Play to 2.5 and Spring Context to 4.2.5 and running into issues with JPA

Tags: playframework, spring-data

I'm specifically upgrading from Play Framework 2.4 to 2.5 and Spring Context 4.2.1 to 4.2.5

I'm running into issues using spring repository where the entity manager is no longer committing despite having @Transactional annotations.

Is this a Play or Spring context issue?

Comment: Impossible to say without more information. Could you share the code? Is the transactional annotation from spring or play?

Comment: It is from play.

The lack of persistence occurs when using the default persistent for the entity manager.

Comment: Please, add the problematic code to the question.

Comment: Could you please share the code and also compare the before and after migration?